# Find Magnet in android

Tags: android, sensors

**What I am trying for :-**
I would like to find magnet using my android device.

**What I have done yet :-**
I am registering my sensor of type magnetic field like this

```
Sensor magnetometer = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
```

and in `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` method I am getting x,y,z from event.value if type is magnetic field.

Upto this everything is fine, then I get absolute value from these three values using 
`Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z))` and I get one absolute value.

 But I think this is something only related to device because when I keep one magnet closer to my device nothing happens(neither absolute value nor its (x,y,z) changes.

Thanks.

Comment: This could be a hardware failure. Are you sure your device is actually working? Did you try any other app that uses the magnetic field? Did this thirdy-part app work? Did you try your code on another device?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your device does not measure your magnet but the magnetic field of the earth. And independent from the orientation of your device when you concatenate the values this way you always get back the same value. Except the returned value is always 0, then you simply measure nothing and it could be a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie on Android development too and was interested in creating a similar app, where i get notified when a magnet is brought sufficiently near to my phone.

I used the same formula for calculating the net Magnetic Field, and if u refer to this Android Documentation on Sensor Managers [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html), u will find that MAX and MIN values for the Earth's Magnetic Field.

My app uses the same range to detect a magnet and it works fine. Depending upon the "promixity" you require, you can tweak the values as you wish.

In case, you don't notice any considerable difference in field values upon bringing a magnet closer, i think, that is some hardware issue.